# Como implementar uma fila de threads para serem executadas uma após a outra?

Tags: c#, thread, fila-thread

Possuo um método estático para gravar o logs em meu sistema.

```cs
public class Logger
{
    public static void SaveLog(string[] lines)
    {
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\...\Temp\ExceptLog.txt", lines);
    }
}
```

O método é utilizado em vários lugares e acessam o mesmo arquivo de texto.

Gostaria de saber como implementar em C# uma fila de threads para evitar conflito no acesso concorrido ao arquivo.

Como pode ser feito uma fila de threads para executar, uma a uma em segundo plano, de forma a evitar o conflito ao acesso concorrente e com isso não "atrapalhar" a thread principal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em vez de criar uma fila de threads, porque não criar uma fila de mensagens que vão ser escritas? Assim poderia ter uma thread exclusiva que escrevia as mensagens e evitava o problema de acesso, criando assim um sistema de produtores/consumidor.

Os passos, de grosso modo, seriam:

1. Colocar o código de escrita do log dentro de uma acção;
2. Colocar essa acção numa `blocking collection`;
3. Ter uma `thread` dedicada ao logging que consuma a `blocking collection` e execute as acções recebidas, assim garante a escrita sequencial dos logs no ficheiro;

Uma implementação baseada nos pontos atrás:

```
var LogCollection = new BlockingCollection<Action>();

public static void LogMessage(string messageToLog)
{
    LogCollection.Add(() => File.WriteAllText("", messageToLog));
}

public static void WriteLogMessages(CancellationToken token)
{ 
    foreach (var msg in LogCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable(token))
    {
        msg();
    }
}
```

Utilizando ficaria assim:

```
public static void Main()
{
    using (CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
    {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(() => WriteLogMessages(cts.Token));
        t1.Start();
        LogMessage("Hello World");
        Console.ReadKey();
        cts.Cancel();
        t1.Join();
    }
}
```

Nota:
Para mais ideias, e caso esteja decidido em usar a sua própria implementação de log, dê uma vista de olhas no código do [NLog](https://github.com/NLog/NLog) para mais inspiração.